# What is the purpose of glTranslatef() method?

Tags: opengl

I am quite a beginner in *openGl*. Can you please tell me about

```
glTranslatef();  
glScalef();
glBegin ();
```

I have searched for them in google but couldn't get the answer.

Thankyou

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- **glTranslate** produces a translation by x y z . The current matrix (see [glMatrixMode](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml)) is multiplied by this translation matrix,
  with the product replacing the current matrix, as if `glMultMatrix`
  were called with the following matrix for its argument:

  ```
  1 0 0 x 
  0 1 0 y 
  0 0 1 z 
  0 0 0 1
  ```

  If the matrix mode is either `GL_MODELVIEW` or `GL_PROJECTION`, all
  objects drawn after a call to glTranslate are translated.

  Use `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` to save and restore the
  untranslated coordinate system.

  More information about [glTranslate](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTranslate.xml)
- **glScale** produces a nonuniform scaling along the x, y, and z axes. The three parameters indicate the desired scale factor along each of
  the three axes.

  The current matrix (see [glMatrixMode](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml)) is multiplied by this
  scale matrix, and the product replaces the current matrix as if
  glMultMatrix were called with the following matrix as its argument:

  ```
  x 0 0 0 
  0 y 0 0 
  0 0 z 0 
  0 0 0 1
  ```

  If the matrix mode is either `GL_MODELVIEW` or `GL_PROJECTION`, all
  objects drawn after glScale is called are scaled.

  Use `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` to save and restore the unscaled
  coordinate system.

  More information about [glScale](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glScale.xml)
- **glBegin** and **glEnd** delimit the vertices that define a primitive or a group of like primitives. glBegin accepts a single
  argument that specifies in which of ten ways the vertices are
  interpreted. Taking n as an integer count starting at one, and N as
  the total number of vertices specified.

  More information on [glBegin](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBegin.xml)

Comment: if we use 
    `glTranslatef();`
     and `glScalef();` together what effect will be taken plece

Comment: I am extremely new.. please help me

Comment: glTranslate get the position of the objects just like ex-glTranslatef(1,1,2); and  glScalef() scale it as multiply the current matrix by a general scaling matrix.like this glscalef(10,10,10)

Comment: Scale, just like Rotate, operates from the origin and important thing is 
Don't forget to use  transformations in the required order

Answer (score 4):

DoughnutZombie - has given the valid & correct answer.

but, in simple terms, IIRC you can think of them a little like:

- glTranslate lets you "move" things
- glScale is to scale them
- and glBegin to let opengl know you are about to give something, like a list of vertices to draw a triangle

You will indeed need to use pushmatrix and popmatrix

All of these should be covered in most newcomers tutorials, may I recommend the legacy tutorials at http://nehe.gamedev.net/

Comment: Easy & useful comment.